# How to pass connection string to DataContext in EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application and have the following piece of code:

```
public HAZID_DataContext() : base("HAZIDDEV")
{
    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UseScopeIdentity = false;
}
```

I want to be able to set `HAZIDDEV` based on what my work environment is set to.

For example in the web config we have the following

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HAZIDTEST" connectionString="Server=DTISQLVS02\DEVELOPMENT;Database=HAZID;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="HAZIDDEV" connectionString="Server=DTIDEV27;Database=HAZIDDEV;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

and would like to have a variable in the web config like this

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

<add key="DefaultCulture" value="en" />
<add key="WorkEnvironment" value="Development"/>
<add key="PrefixDefaultCulture" value="false" />
<add key="SupportedCultures" value="en,fr" />
</appSettings>
```

So I could have a `HAZIDDEV`, `HAZIDTEST` and `HAZIDPROD` connection string and if I look at the application setting `WorkEnvironment` and it is `Development` then I will use `HAZIDDEV` as the connection.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated

Comment: please explain what do u mean by work environment ?

Comment: @Carl Cummings: The parameter in the `base("HAZIDDEV")` is the name of the connection string from the configuration file. Therefore, you just need modify the configuration file for each environment accordingly.

Comment: Thanks all we are doing that now but where hoping there was a way to have all our connection string in the config and base off another flag use the correct connection string.

I modified the question a biut mopre to add more code of what we where thinking but it may nbot be possoble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to have separate connection strings for different environments then you should not be separating the connection string variables. Instead vary the value of the connection string.

Configure your DBContext object to be like the follwing:

```
public partial class HAZID_DataContext : DbContext
{
        public HAZID_DataContext()
        {
        }

        public HAZID_DataContext(DbContextOptions<HAZID_DataContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        //Other codes goes here

}
```

Then inject the connection string in app startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<HAZID_DataContext>(opts =>
 opts.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HAZIDDEV")));
    
    ...
}
```

Then in the appsettings.json file for MVC Core:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "HAZIDDEV": "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS2012;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=abc;Password=abc"
  }
}
```

Or Read from web.config or other config file this way:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HAZIDDEV"].ConnectionString;
```

Just change the value of the connection string based on environments. Or have multiple connection strings as required.

Comment: Thanks for the rely but I am using EntityFramework not EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: The idea was to show you how you can have different connection string on different environments. The code above would be the same except the connection string part. You are reading the connection string from the web config or another config file right? Just replace the connection string reading source part. Then you can still have multiple connection strings and read the one based on environment.

Comment: Ah I see. my problem was I was trying to implement this but could not find the required libraries to use. Thanks though as this has gotten me to do some more learning and digging into how this all works.

Comment: @CarlCummings I have updated the answer. Check the sample codes.